# How to call Action Helper as broker method in View Helper?

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

I have Action Helper that is database abstraction layer.

I would like to access it in View Helper to read and present some data from the model.

In Controller I call Action Helper as broker method, but how to achieve the same in View Helper?

Somewhere in controller:

```
$this->_helper->Service("Custom\\PageService");
```

Service.php:

```
...
public function direct($serviceClass)
{
    return new $serviceClass($this->em);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicer way will be to create a view helper inside it do

```
  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('service')->direct("Custom\\PageService");
```

another way would be inside controller init method do

```
$this->view->helper = $this->_helper;
```

so in view (phtml) you can do

```
$this->helper->Service("Custom\\PageService");
```

Comment: Question remain which would be better solution. I think that the first because then you are not dependent on `Controller`. What do You think?